# Spring HATEOAS with Traverson

Tags: hateoas, spring-hateoas, hal, hypermedia

I'm using **spring-hateoas:0.18.0.RELEASE** with **spring-boot:1.2.5.RELEASE**

For calling my Web Service and going through *HAL* links i'm using ***Traverson Client*** *(API for client side service traversal inspired by the Traverson JavaScript library)*

[Spring Hateoas Traverson Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.18.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#client)

It's new for working with *Hypermedia* and *HateoasRest*

My question is when do I need to use ***PagedResources*** and ***Resource***?

Example I found here [Traverson Client examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.hateoas.client.Traverson) :

```
 final PagedResources<Resource<Customer>> resources = traverson
            .follow("customers","search","findByFirstName")
            .withTemplateParameters(parameters)
            .toObject(new TypeReferences.PagedResourcesType<Resource<Customer>>(){});
```

The code I wrote is :

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<Resource<ProjectJSON>> resourceParameterizedTypeReference = new
                ParameterizedTypeReference<Resource<ProjectJSON>>() {};

Resource<ProjectJSON> projectJSONResource = traverson
            .follow("projects")
            .follow("$._embedded.projects[0]._links.self.href")
            .toObject(resourceParameterizedTypeReference);
```

I know it's not the same thing, but what is the best practice with resources when calling ***Traverson.toObject()*** method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple: you use `PagedResources` when you are returning lots of items, and you use `Resource` when you are returning a single item. So when returning many `Customer` objects you might want to paginate them, and you'd use `PagedResources<Resource<Customer>>`. For a single customer it'd be `Resource<Customer>`.

The `Resource` just wraps the domain object and adds links to it. If you don't need links now and you know you don't need the links in the future either, you could go without the `Resource` as well.

The `PagedResources` adds page metadata for selecting the page number and page size. It also allows the server to send the information on the total number of pages and the total number of items. You could ask a paged resource to send you page 2 with page size of 5, and you'd get items 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10.